# Alkyl halide reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reactivity, halides

In the following the reaction ,

According to me the product should be compound  (A) due to substitution reaction.

But the product formed is the compound (B) , what could be the mechanism for the reaction for that product.

[image]

Comment: Part of product B is missing. I assume it is meant to be just a methyl group.

Comment: @bon yes you are correct , it is methyl group only .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reflect on the comments below:
In literature this reaction seems to actually produce product A and synthesis of product B seems to require much more exotic conditions than described in the question. As such I have to conclude that the correct answer would have be A.

---

Old answer:

Due to the polar aprotic solvent (DMF) one would think Sn2 is favoured as the reaction mechanism, however if the product is indeed B it would suggest an Sn1 mechanism where the aromatic ring stabilises the cation. One of the resulting resonance structures would indeed react with fluoride. Due to the stability of aromatics the product is formed by re-aromatisation.

[image]

Comment: This is what I suspected must be the case but I can't give a good reason why the fluoride attacks at the *ortho* position rather than the benzyl position.

Comment: @bon If the primary carbocation is formed it will easily resonate to the secondary, much more stable, carbocation. Therefore the _ortho_ position doesn't surprise me as much as the Sn1 mechanism does.

Comment: The secondary, non-aromatic resonance form, is more stable than the primary, aromatic resonance form...? Benzyl carbocations don't react on the ring

Comment: @orthocresol It struck me as weird the first time I saw similar mechanisms as well, but yes the aromaticity can be broken for such stabilization. However, I cannot find any mention of a synthesis _ortho_-fluorotoluene from benzyl bromide in literature. bon, are you sure B is the correct answer?

Comment: I have no idea what the correct answer is. I didn't ask the question. I too was unable to find any reference to this in the literature though so I suspect it may be wrong.

Comment: I just looked up the accepted ways of synthesising _ortho_-fluorotoluene and they are way more exotic conditions than these Finkelstein conditions. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Why the reaction proceeds like this ?

Comment: @koolman Which reaction are you asking about, to give A or to give B? To A would be due to the solvent (polar aprotic) promoting an Sn2 reaction, which occurs do to the higher stability of the fluoride (A) than the bromide (starting material).

Comment: Why B compond is formed ?

Comment: @koolman Well as you can read from my answer I actually highly doubt it would be in this reaction as none of the literature I was able to find supports that idea. I was wondering: who or what mentioned B as the correct answer to you?